# Is there an easy way to force the user to use Internet Explorer, ideally without installing anything new?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, browser

I am working on 4 internal websites, everyone should be using IE but not everyone is.

Is there an easy way to force the user to use IE, ideally without installing anything new like JQuery?

Cheers,
Kohan

---

### Addendum

I really shouldn't have to justify why i'm wanting to do this, but here goes.

This site is totally internal and 98% of the users do not have the rights to install a new browser... however there are a select few that do. This is fine for most of our sites, but since these sites are very old, they do not work in anything but IE. I could fix it for all browsers... but it is a better use of my time to just put a "hot-fix" in for now as it will likely all get rewritten next year. The site itself is also only used once a year. It's simply not worth the time investment in this case.

Thanks
Kohan.

Comment: People are still creating browser-specific web applications these days?

Comment: What? (a) what user (b) what else instead of IE (c) what has JQuery got to do with it? Straightforward answers: **A** don't install anything else (guarantees they use IE) **B** make your site unusable in other browsers - drop an ActiveX bomb(guarantees no-one will _use_ another browser) **C** Generic approach: don't build a website (no one will visit the site with something else than IE)

Comment: My related question: How can I force the user *not* to use Internet Explorer?

Comment: @LarryLustig: you can't. You can induce most individuals by simply letting them watch you use Opera or Chrome for, say, a minute. But caged specimens will have no choice and some specimens have involved into a sado-masochistic subtype :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber, you don't know the reason for this requirement. Some companies have certified some software to use on critical data, so they will get problems with an audit if the data accessible with other software.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Why not, it cut's development time and costs.

Comment: @GvS: so that makes it the company's problem **and** solution: they can simply prevent anything from being installed on their _certified desktops_. That's how certification works: it leaves no room for deviations (incidentally that was my option **A**)

Comment: @sehe, it was just an example. Companies are not big monolitic blocks that never change you know. Sometimes they have to integrate a takeover that was standardized on other softwhare, that they need for other actions.

Comment: @GvS: that's a lot of hot air. What is the point? It still revolves about defining a standard. You _cannot_ in the general case, prevent people using other browsers as long as other browsers do exist. That's a simple fact. You can, however, control a desktop environment (to a certain - fairly high - degree) and that's what e.g. military agencies use.

Comment: @sehe, so the OP gets the requirement as if he is in a military agency, the mess from a big company, and the budget from a small company, so he ends up seeking free consultancy on StackOverflow.

Comment: Wow; all I did was ask a question. I had no idea it would be considered "hostility"! :)

Comment: Chill with people hating the fact that he 'has' to do this.. I have 'had' to code things certain ways due to tiny deadlines and stuff in the past, Never proud of it, but it has to be done some times. In the 1 year time when they come to rebuild the website using non-browser specific ways, he can go back to his code and change it to `if (browser == "IE") { alert("get a better browser") }` but until that day, he HAS to do this. Simple as.

Comment: For the record, I don't question the _need_ behind the question. My initial comment was really qualifying the question itself, which could use a lot of improvement in the areas (a,b,c) I mentioned. The rest of my comment is actually _helpful_ in that I outline the broad range of actions you could take. Without a more precise question, I'm not inclined to make any specific recommendation. **Edit** With the 'addendum' the question makes sense. I feel that the 'best' answers have already been given for that scenario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really wanted to do this you could check the user agent of each request and if it's not IE redirect to a holding page explaining that they need to change browsers.

`var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;`

Alternatively use the Request.Browser property.

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser != "IE")
{
   // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: This works unless the user has switched the user agent, which is easy to do, so that Firefox returns a user agent string that says that it's IE.  So then you can start digging into browser capabilities;  for example, whether DOM elements support the attachEvent (IE) versus addEventListener (other) methods.  But IE 9 is moving closer to DOM compliance and I'm not sure whether it still supports the attachEvent method.  So if you define "IE" as "supports attachEvent" then IE 9 might look like "not IE".  And if IE 4 matters, it didn't support either method.

Comment: @dnuttle if this is an internal intranet thing to a company, then most wont even know what a useragent is, and for those who actually know what a useragent is, if they try and trick the site into thinking its got the right browser, and it doesn't work, then they will know their little trick doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You could find the browser type, and if its not IE, then do a `Response.Redirect()` to a generic "Use IE" page.

```
if (!(Request.Browser=="IE")){
   Response.Redirect("UseIE.aspx");
}
```

You'll have to check the return values of `Request.Browser` though as I'm not certain without testing

Comment: Yup: option **B** (make the site unusable for other browsers). Not pretty, and spoofable. But hey, it is an effort

Comment: @sehe I wouldn't agree that a site should be blocked from all browsers but IE, but this is what the OP wants. It's never going to be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest something eretical: instead of fighting against Internet Explorer, force the users to use the [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) It's a "plugin" for Internet Explorer that make the page work as if they were in Chrome.

I'll quote from that page:

> Google Chrome Frame is an open source plug-in that seamlessly brings
> Google Chrome's open web technologies and speedy JavaScript engine to
> Internet Explorer. With Google Chrome Frame, you can:
>
> - Start using open
>   web technologies - like the HTML5 canvas tag - right away, even
>   technologies that aren't yet supported in Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8,
>   or 9.
> - Take advantage of JavaScript performance improvements to make
>   your apps faster and more responsive.

Now your users can have IE 6.0 to work with their obsolete internal web applications AND you can work against a "unified" (you are programming only against Chrome) "modern" web browser.

Comment: These specific sites do not work in Chrome, installing that will result in IE not working either. I did make the case for using Chrome frame but it was decided against as we do scheduled updates. It would not be good if chrome updated itself and brought down all our sites.